# What is the equivalent of Java's SimpleDateFormat class in C#?

Tags: c#, java

Anyone knows an equivalent class of Java's SimpleDateFormat in C#? I wonder if i can convert the following java code using Custom Date and Time Format Strings in C#

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US); 
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
str = format.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `DateTime`'s `ToString()` method and specify the [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that you want the `DateTime` to be output in. In this case:

```
// US culture
var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// Get current UTC time.   
var utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
// Change time to match GMT + 1.
var gmt1Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcDate, "W. Europe Standard Time");
// Output the GMT+1 time in our specified format using the US-culture. 
var str = gmt1Date.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", usCulture);
```

Please note that .NET's equivalent of EEE is ddd.